# Display context menu on mouse right click on a task

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

Is it possible to display an actionable context menu on right click on a task/row in a Kendo UI Gantt chart.

The demo and the examples do not seem to point in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [filter option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu#configuration-filter) of the Context Menu in order to display it for specific elements only. In the current case the **k-task** CSS class could be used. Here is a [small example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uMICA).